# zend 2 + doctrine 2 hydrator - the hydrator is not hydratating POST objects

Tags: forms, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am having problems getting my doctrine hydrator to hydrate my return post forms.

Post forms.

I keep getting the following message:

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO worker_essay
>   (title) VALUES (?)' with params [null]: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1048 Column 'title' cannot be null

but this cannot be correct because  I have a validator on my form requiring this value to be inserted, yet my form is validating.

I would really appreciate any help or advice on resolving the problem or advice on how to go about discovering what is causing the problem.

```
public function getInputFilterSpecification()
  {
        return array(
            'title' => array(
                'required' => true
            ),
        );
    }
```

these are the var_dumped values from the returned form:

```
object(Zend\Stdlib\Parameters)[146]   public 'WorkerStatement' => 
     array (size=2)
       'id' => string '' (length=0)
       'title' => string 'the values from title' (length=21)   public 'submit' => string 'Submit' (length=6)
```

As you can see, the values are clearly there, which means that the problem might be in the hydrators.

I now enclosed the rest of the documents.

**The Controller**

```
public function workerStatementAction()
    {
         $form = new CreateWorkerStatementForm($this->getEntityManager());

         $workerStatement = new WorkerStatement();
      //  $form->setInputFilter($workerEssay->getInputFilter());
         $form->bind($workerStatement);
       //    var_dump($workerStatement); die();
          if ($this->request->isPost()) {
            $post  = $this->request->getPost();
            $form  =  $form->setData($this->request->getPost());
             if ($form->isValid()) {
                $post =$this->request->getPost();
                  $this->getEntityManager()->persist($workerStatement);
                 $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
             // Redirect to list of aboutyou
             return $this->redirect()->toRoute('worker');    
             }
         }
         return array('form' => $form);

    }
```

The fieldset

```
class WorkerStatementFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
   public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        parent::__construct('WorkerStatement');


        $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager, 'Workers\Entity\WorkerStatement'))
             ->setObject(new WorkerStatement());


  $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'title',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'title',
            ),
        ));

}
```

** The Form**

```
class CreateWorkerStatementForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        parent::__construct('WorkerStatement');

        // The form will hydrate an object of type "AboutYou"
        $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager, 'Workers\Entity\WorkerStatement'));

        // Add the user fieldset, and set it as the base fieldset
      $workerStatementFieldset = new WorkerStatementFieldset($objectManager);
      $workerStatementFieldset->setUseAsBaseFieldset(true);
      $this->add($workerStatementFieldset);
 }
}
```

Here is the `var_daump` of the persist in the controller:

```
 $this->getEntityManager()->persist($workerStatement);



object(Workers\Entity\WorkerStatement)[351]
  protected 'id' => null
  protected 'title' => null
```

You will note that they are empty, yet the var dump of the values from the returned post clearly contain the values.

I enclose my workstatement class. you will note that I have used the magic getter/setter.

```
<?php

namespace Workers\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\InputFilter\Factory as InputFactory;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterAwareInterface;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface; 

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="worker_essay")
 * @property string $title
 */
class WorkerStatement   
{


    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    protected $id;


     /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
* Magic getter to expose protected properties.
*
* @param string $property
* @return mixed
*/
public function __get($property)
{
return $this->$property;
}

/**
* Magic setter to save protected properties.
*
* @param string $property
* @param mixed $value
*/
public function __set($property, $value)
{
$this->$property = $value;
}




     public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {
        return array(

            'title' => array(
                'required' => true
            )
        );
    }


}
```

Comment: Please paste your entity. Maybe you forgot about the title getter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DoctrineHydrator` by default is hydrating and extracting values using getters and setters. If your entity doesn't have these methods then it cannot work properly. If you dont' want to use getters/setters, use `new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager, 'Workers\Entity\WorkerStatement', false)` instead of `new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager, 'Workers\Entity\WorkerStatement')`.

Maybe it's not the reason why hydrator doesn't work. Please edit your first post and paste `Workers\Entity\WorkerStatement` class.

EDIT

Hydrator is calling getTitle() and your magic method is trying to access getTitle property which doesn't exist. You have three options:

1. Change DoctrineHydrator to `new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager, 'Workers\Entity\WorkerStatement', false)`.
2. Add getters and setters. For example `getTitle()`, `setTitle($title)`.
3. Refactor magic methods to accept getProperty, setProperty.

Comment: hello Adrian.Thank you for responding. I have amended my original post to include my workStatement Class. you will see that i have indeed used the magic getter/setter. so, i am at a complete loss why its not working.Any help/advice/assistance will be very appriciated

Comment: Please check again my answer.

Comment: Hello Adrian. i actaully intially tried to use the getTitle() and setTitle() but it made no diffrence. it still did not work

Comment: Hello Adrian. it worked now. thank you so much. i have no idea why it failed to work before. i actually used the getTitle and setTitle before. But much appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually You dont need to add the hydrator in the form , use it in the controller (or service) if its necessary .

plz add a var dump before :

```
$this->getEntityManager()->persist($workerStatement);
```

and post the result

Comment: hi sina. thank yoiu so much for responding. here is the result of my var dump of the entity prior to the persist. object(Workers\Entity\WorkerStatement)[351]
  protected 'id' => null
  protected 'title' => null

Comment: Hi again sina. i have edited my original post and posted the values from the var dump of the persist. warm regards